# CiviEvent - On Waitlist will not Enable in Participant Status - Wordpress site - "Enable" word toggle greyed out - how to Enable?

Tags: civievent, waitlist

Testing out CiviEvent.
We whish to enable waitlists, but when we go to the Participant Status window, the line for "On Waitlist" and "Pending from Waitlist" are greyed out.  Trying to click on "Enable" does nothting.
How can we get waitlists enabled for events?
Wordpress site with Civc CRM as a plugin

Comment: I just tried it on the demo site and clicking enable works there. Can you try it there to confirm? https://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Comment: And it does work fine on the demo site......I did confirm it there.   Now to figure out what is different between our wordpress site and the demo site.  I set up a user for you to check if could.  https://conordicclub.org/cagney/wp-admin/admin with the "demo" and "demo"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a problem that jQuery isn't loading. I see this in the console:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://conordicclub.org/cagney/wp-admin/admin.php?page=CiviCRM&q=civicrm%2Fadmin%2Fparticipant_status&reset=1' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure script 'http://conordicclub.org/cagney/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/js/jquery/jquery.crmEditable.js?r=YrcT7en_US'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

Seems like some kind of issue with the base url or something along those lines.

Comment: Thanks - will take a look